# How to find element in XML Data Island using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

How can I use jQuery to output an XML data island? Here is an example of my code:

```
<script id="XML" type="application/xml">
    <designs>
        <design id="17161" style="44DSW" image="/500.jpg"></design>
    </designs>
</script>
```

```js
console.log( jQuery('designs design[id="17161"]').attr('style') );
```

The output should be: `44DSW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`jQuery.parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse string into XML document. Parsed xml is like HTML document and you can find your element in it.

```js
var xml = $.parseXML($('#XML').text());
var style = $(xml).find('design[id="17161"]').attr('style');
console.log(style);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="XML" type="application/xml">
  <designs>
    <design id="17161" style="44DSW" image="/500.jpg"></design>
  </designs>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use next syntax:

```js
console.log($($("#XML").text()).find("design")[0].attributes.style.value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script id="XML" type="application/xml">
   <designs>
  <design id="17161" style="44DSW" image="/500.jpg"></design>
   </designs>
 </script>
```